# Tortoise SVN Very Slow on Windows 7 x64

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64

I have a Windows 7 x64 machine with Tortoise SVN 32 and 64 bits installed side-by-side. I have a dedicated server with Subversion installed under Apache.

The repository can be accessed via TSVN from other Vista machines without problems. I can access the repository on the server without problems from any browser.

However, when I try to use TSVN for any operation which involves calling the server (e.g. Show Log, Commit, Update) it takes about 5-10 minutes for the operation to start but it's completed in the end. Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming problems.

Comment: The side-by-side installation is perfectly ok, as stated on the developer's site. However I had this problem even with only TSVN 64 installed.

Comment: As an update I found out that RapidSVN behaves the same as TortoiseSVN so it's not a TSVN related problem. Again, I can access my repository without problems from the browser.

Comment: This is a programming related question, isn't it? How can one write code without his toolset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was caused by my internet security suite, BitDefender x64. It was not simply a problem of disabling the Firewall or the entire suite, this just did not work.

I found some tutorials on the BitDefender forums for how to exclude TortoiseSVN from the scan, this required a reboot in safe mode!